# A curious case of Benjamin Button

Tags: calculation-puzzle

In 1980, Jack has an age of 20. In 1985 however, he is only 15 years old.

How did he age backwards?

Comment: shouldn't this be the curious case of jack button?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jack lives in 1980 BC.  Of course, back then, they were counting forward from a different starting point. :)

Comment: But in 1980 BC, they didn't know that Christ would come, so why were they counting forward?

Comment: Jack lives on the planet ORK.

Comment: The question never said that Jack himself stated the year. He might have said that he was born in the second year of the reign of Amenemhat.  But *we* know that is 1960 BC, so I call it a good riddle.