# A Second Benjamin Button

Tags: word-problem, calculation-puzzle

This was inspired by [A curious case of Benjamin Button](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2432/a-curious-case-of-benjamin-button) but has a different solution.

In 1980 AD (or 1980 CE, if you prefer), Jack has an age of 20. In 1985 however, he is only 6 years old.

How did Jack age backwards?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Jack is 20 months old in 1980.

He is 6 years old in 1985.

Answer (score 7):

He was born on leap day, Feb 29 1960.  So in 1980 his legal age would be 20, but by 1985 only 6 additional leap years have occurred.

Comment: The wording would have to be "he has only had 6 birthdays".  If the anniversery is skipped a year has still passed.

Comment: This is a good solution, but it is not the one I had intended.

Answer (score 4):

Jack is a fictional character first published in 1979.  In the story is set in 1980 (or the sequel published 1980 or something), he is a 20 year old.